# Pivot dataframe and get two value columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataset there look like this:

| Region | Country | ProductGroup | Category | ProductFamily | value | other info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DK | Europe | X | y | Z | 1/2 | X |
| DE | Europe | X1 | y1 | Z1 | 1/12 | - |
| US | Americas | X | y | Z | 6/9 | - |

I Would like to have a pivot like this

```
                                             Region
                                             Europe                                  Americas
                                             DK                   DE                 US
                                             Value Other info     Value Other info   Value Other info
ProductGroup    Category    ProductFamily
C               Y           Z                1/2  X                                  6/9  -
X1              Y1          Z1                                     1/12  -
```

I have tried this

```
x = df_out.pivot(index=['MATKL','ProductGroup','Category','ProductFamily'], 
                 columns=['Region','Country'], values = ['value','Eother info'])
```

It does nearly the job, but it give me two blocks on for value and then all region, countries and then the same for Other info.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
x = (df_out.pivot(index=['ProductGroup','Category','ProductFamily'], 
                 columns=['Region','Country'], values = ['value','other info'])
     .reorder_levels([1,2,0], axis=1)
     .sort_index(axis=1, level=[0,1], sort_remaining=False))
print (x)
Region                                  DE                DK             \
Country                             Europe            Europe              
                                     value other info  value other info   
ProductGroup Category ProductFamily                                       
X            y        Z                NaN        NaN    1/2          X   
X1           y1       Z1              1/12          -    NaN        NaN   

Region                                    US             
Country                             Americas             
                                       value other info  
ProductGroup Category ProductFamily                      
X            y        Z                  6/9          -  
X1           y1       Z1                 NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.set_index([*df][:-2]).unstack([0,1]).swaplevel(0,-1, axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
```